# Create Unusual Recurring Outlook Event: First Saturday Following the 18th of Every Month

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, office365

For IT maintenance, I'm about to set up a recurring event in Outlook 365, shared with several attendees across several timezones. 
The event is scheduled to occur on the **first Saturday Following the 18th of Every Month** - thus dates can be 19-25, both included. In other words, this will occur on either the 3rd or 4th Saturday of the month.

I've tried the following:

1. Looking through the available GUI options, it appear nested rules are impossible.
2. In the past have been guided to use VBA to set up the event,
   but on Outlook 365 that's not an option.
3. It's easy to specify as an iCalendar event like this `RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=SA;BYMONTHDAY=19,20,21,22,23,24,25` but it appear to be impossible to import it into Outlook, without using an Outlook Desktop Extension and syncing with an entire iCalendar.
4. Creating it in crontab is similar easy (here set at 16:00): `0 16 19,20,21,22,23,24,25 * 6`, but unfortunately outlook calendar does not seem to support the crontab format in any way.

So I've hit the limit of my ideas, and hope some of you can share some wisdom.

Comment: Have you ever tried Microsoft Flows?

Comment: @varfirstName Thank you for the suggestion. No, I haven't tried Microsoft Flows. The web site intro looks like it may be used, but unfortunately it's not on the list of programs available to me through my company's 365 subscription. :-(

Comment: What does your company have? It's included in O365 ProPlus.

Comment: @varfirstName I'm unsure exactly what subscription my company have, but there's only a subset of the regular 365 applications available. This morning I did try to log onto Flow using my private account, but looking through the templates available I failed to find anything that appeared to be able to create a recurring event in calendar similar to the requirements. Can you recommend somewhere to look?

Comment: Do you have Outlook 2016 on your computer? Outlook 2016 has VBA and macro support.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have anything but 365. I might be able to find an external computer with Outlook 2016 and send an invitation to the event, but only for the initial invite/creation. Subsequent edits of any/all events must happen in the cloud. The more I look at this, the less I think it's possible - unless some kind of Outlook365 extension plugin exists!? I start fearing that I have to setup all the events by hand

Comment: Outlook 2016 is what you currently get via Office 365. It may be slightly ahead of the non-subscription version, too.